# Secured communication between two web servers (Amazon EC2 with Django and Google App Engine)

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, amazon-ec2, urllib

I have a website which uses Amazon EC2 with Django and Google App Engine for its powerful Image API and image serving infrastructure. When a user uploads an image the browser makes an AJAX request to my EC2 server for the Blobstore upload url. I'm fetching this through my Django server so I can check whether the user is authenticated or not and then the server needs to get the url from the App Engine server. After the upload is complete and processed in App Engine I need to send the upload info back to the django server so I can build the required model instances. How can I accomplish this? I was thinking to use urllib but how can I secure this to make sure the urls will only get accessed by my servers only and not by a web user? Maybe some sort of secret key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

apart from the Https call ( which you should be making to transfer info to django ), you can go with AES encryption ( use Pycrypto/ any other lib). It takes a secret key to encrypt your message.

Answer (score 1):

For server to server communication, traditional security advice would recommend some sort of IP range restriction at the web server level for the URLs in addition to whatever default security is in place. However, since you are making the call from a cloud provider to another cloud provider, your ability to permanently control the IP address of either the client and the server may diminished.

That said, I would recommend using a standard username/password authentication mechanism and HTTPS for transport security. A basic auth username/password would be my recommendation(`https:\\username:password@appengine.com\`). In addition, I would make sure to enforce a lockout based on a certain number of failed attempts in a specific time window. This would discourage attempts to brute force the password.

Depending on what web framework you are using on the App Engine, there is probably already support for some or all of what I just mentioned. If you update this question with more specifics on your architecture or open a new question with more information, we could give you a more accurate recommendation.

Answer (score 1):

[SDC](https://developers.google.com/secure-data-connector/) provides a secure tunnel from AppEngine to a private network elsewhere -- which could be your EC2 instance, if you run it there.